# Webpack and Bootstrap problems

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

I'm quite new to Webpack and NodeJS, so I'm doing simple tests just to learn. I'm developing a new website and here's my idea:

I have a vendor.ts file that I can put all my vendors js and css:

```js
    // Angular 2
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/router';

// RxJS
import 'rxjs';

// Bootstrap
import 'bootstrap';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

//jQuery
import 'jquery';
```

So, here's my webpack config:

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');


module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/app/main.ts'
  },

  output: {
    path: './src/public/',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },

  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['ts', 'angular2-template-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      { 
        test: /\.css$/, 
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({fallbackLoader: "style-loader", loader: "css-loader?souceMap"}) 
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css")
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    }),

    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    })  
  ]
};
```

When I'm running 'webpack' command, it throws me the error:

> ERROR in ./src/vendor.ts Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve
> module '[object Object]' in /home/xxxxx/xxxx/xxxxx-xxxx/src  @
> ./src/vendor.ts 13:0-59

Does anybody could help me?

Thanks!

EDIT: the solution can be find at https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/215

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution can be find at https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/215

Thanks!

Comment: can you specify exactly what you did?

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong to do so `import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'`.
With non-code files you have to use `require` instead, like `require( '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css')`.

This article could be helpful https://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html

Comment: But I'm getting this error with every css file that webpack is trying to import.
My app.component.ts uses app.component.css and is getting the same error..

Comment: After trying to change import for require, still got the error :(

Comment: I think I found the reason - you should move the line `new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css")` in config to all plugins (where `new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin` is), because now you are trying to add 'plugins' property to a 'module' property instead of all plugins of config

Comment: Oleg, thanks for you response, but after modifying it, still got the error :-(

Comment: Finally I got it working: https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/215

Just changed my css loader to: loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css-loader!postcss-loader') as commented in the issue.

Comment: @GuilhermeChiara so write an answer and accept it. Current one is misleading.